# Randomly splitting a dynamic range into equal groups

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a dynamic range of values that I want to split into N groups, where N is specified by the user.

I want to do the following:

- Split the group into N equal parts.
- Specify which ones in the range that are to be in separate groups.
- Have a "checker" to see if the math works out and it is possible to do (i.e. a group of 11 cannot be split into 2 groups).

Here is a scenario:

- I have a list of 26 values (an array of letters, A to Z).
- I want two groups, randomly split.
- I specified 2 of the values where I want them to be separate (i.e. the letter B and X).

This should give me two groups, 13 values of "Group 1" and 13 values of "Group 2".

"Group 1" can contain something like ("B", "N", "V", "C", "T", ..... x 13)

"Group 2" contains ("X", "A", .... x 13)

The variables in this case are the # of values, # of groups to split, and specific values to split.

EDIT: google sheet example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1baZr8QAkFjw1UwsMOyphma6v_MNkWz-aCLx57yPsViE/edit#gid=1454808593

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: @player0 just edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B4<>TRUE,,TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({
 ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B7:B))/(COUNTA(B7:B)/B2)), 
 SORT({RANDARRAY(COUNTA(B7:B)), FILTER(B7:B, B7:B<>"")})}, 
 "select max(Col3) group by Col2 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", 0),,9^9)), " "))))
```

[image]

[image]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(CHAR(96+VLOOKUP(B7:B, {QUERY({B7:B, 
 COUNTIFS(C7:C, C7:C, ROW(C7:C), "<="&ROW(C7:C))*C7:C}, "where Col2<>0"); 
 {FILTER(B7:B, C7:C=FALSE, B7:B<>""), QUERY(SORT({RANDARRAY(SEQUENCE(B1-B2)), 
 ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(B1-B2)/B3), QUERY({
 COUNTIFS(C7:C, C7:C, ROW(C7:C), "<="&ROW(C7:C))*C7:C, B7:B}, 
 "select Col2 where Col1=0 and Col2 is not null")}), "select Col2")}}, 2, 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great start, but not quite what I had in mind.

1) When I change the # of rewards (groups), it should be able to dynamically change.
2) When I change the # of play IDs (values), it should be able to dynamically change.
3) Instead of the groups being split in different columns, I want to see one column to label each of them in their groups beside them.